# How to Check Kgdb is enabled or not?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kgdb

I have a kernel image and would like to debug with kgdb. The `.config` also not available, otherwise I could check the flags in it.

In `/proc/sys/` folder also there is no entry about kgdb.

Is there any way to check whether that image is kgdb enabled or not?

Comment: Have you tried just connecting it. What are you running on, is it an official distribution of a kernel? [Typically, there is .config copied to `/boot/config-<versioningstuff>.origin.arch`
e.g on my FC16 system I have `/boot/config-3.6.6-1.fc16.x86_64`...

Comment: Its unofficial one. while trying to connect, it doesn't wait for kgdb..

Comment: So sounds like it doesn't have kgdb then... Check with whoever built the kernel - yes, I know, it may be a tad difficult today!

Comment: @MatsPetersson, anyway I will check. Meanwhile if u get any alternate method to ensure plz share :)

Comment: Do you have kernel symbols? If so, you could search for `kgdb_arch_init` - I'm 99% sure it's not there in a kernel that has KGBD disabled.

Comment: Any reason for downvote????

Comment: zcat /proc/config.gz > .config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your kernel image was compiled with the options

```
CONFIG_IKCONFIG=y
CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC=y
```

then you can get the kernel image's configuration from `/proc/config.gz` or by using

`/pathtokernelsource/scripts/extract-ikconfig pathtokernelimage > /tmp/config`

From there you can search for `CONFIG_KGDB` using grep or zgrep depending on whether you are viewing the compressed or uncompressed configuration file.

`/pathtokernelsource/scripts/extract-vmlinux pathtokernelimage > /tmp/vmlinux` will also extract the vmlinux executable from the image.

If this has symbols them you can search for kgdb_arch_init or kgdb_arch_* in either the output of nm on this file or in the System.map for your kernel image as **Mats Petersson** mentioned in the comments.

Comment: /proc/config.gz helps me to get the config file. Thanks.